Python Pulp: create constraint for a group of variables
I have a table (called base) like this:



Itinerary
Leg1
Leg2
Bus
Demand
Price




A-B
A-B
-
Bus1
10
20


A-B
A-B
-
Bus2
10
30


A-B-C
A-B
B-C
Bus1
20
60


A-B-C
A-B
B-C
Bus2
30
100


A-B-D
A-B
B-D
Bus1
20
50


A-B-D
A-B
B-D
Bus2
30
40



I have to run an optimization where I have to maximize revenue (passenger * Price) with two constraints. First, passenger number on each 'Itinerary' has to be less than 'Demand' - this one I know how to implement. The second one is: the sum of passengers on each leg has to be less than the leg capacity. Leg capacity is presented in an auxiliary table like this:



Leg
LegCapacity




A-B
40


B-C
50


B-D
60



So my expected outcome would be:



Itinerary
Leg1
Leg2
Bus
Demand
Price
Passengers




A-B
A-B
-
Bus1
10
20



A-B
A-B
-
Bus2
10
30



A-B-C
A-B
B-C
Bus1
20
60
10


A-B-C
A-B
B-C
Bus2
30
100
30


A-B-D
A-B
B-D
Bus1
20
50



A-B-D
A-B
B-D
Bus2
30
40




Passengers number are less than demand and within the leg capacity (in this specific example all itineraries include leg A-B which is not true in my real data - have hundreds of combinations of legs. Also the same leg can be on column Leg1 or Leg2 and the constraint applies disregard which column it is in).
How can I implement it?
My code as of right now is (only with the demand constraint):
prob = lp.LpProblem("testproblem", lp.LpMaximize)

xs = [lp.LpVariable('{}'.format(i+1), lowBound = 0, upBound = base.loc[i,'Capacity']) for i in range(len(base))]

prob += lp.lpSum(x * bv for x,bv in zip(xs, base["Price"]))

prob.solve()


This needs some additional clarity and effort on your part.  You already have capacity in the first table.  How do you reconcile the 2?  Where is the rest of the model?  If you have something that works without the troublesome constraint, edit your post to show that and you have a better chance of getting better help.

Hi! Just edited to make it clearer

That's not any clearer, and doesn't suggest any changes to what I posted.

This is a trivial problem, because there aren't particularly constraints, only bounds (formed from the row-wise minimum of the itinerary capacity and leg capacities). Still, with constraints,
import io

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pulp

with io.StringIO(
'''Itinerary    Leg1    Leg2    Bus     Capacity    Price
A-B     A-B     -   Bus1    10  20
A-B     A-B     -   Bus2    10  30
A-B-C   A-B     B-C     Bus1    20  50
A-B-C   A-B     B-C     Bus2    30  100
A-B-D   A-B     B-D     Bus1    20  50
A-B-D   A-B     B-D     Bus2    30  40
'''
) as f:
    base = pd.read_csv(f, delim_whitespace=True, na_values='-')

base['Label'] = base['Itinerary'].str.replace('-', '') + '_' + base['Bus'].astype(str)
base['Passengers'] = pulp.LpVariable.matrix(
    name='Passengers', indices=base['Label'], cat=pulp.LpInteger,
)

def set_bounds(row: pd.Series) -> None:
    row['Passengers'].bounds(low=0, up=row['Capacity'])
base.apply(set_bounds, axis='columns')


base['Revenue'] = base['Passengers'] * base['Price']
prob = pulp.LpProblem(name='bus_trips', sense=pulp.LpMaximize)
prob.setObjective(pulp.lpSum(base['Revenue']))

with io.StringIO(
'''Leg  LegCapacity
A-B     40
B-C     50
B-D     60
'''
) as f:
    legs = pd.read_csv(
        f, delim_whitespace=True, index_col='Leg',
    )
legs = legs['LegCapacity']

for i_leg in range(1, 3):
    col = f'Leg{i_leg}'
    merged = pd.merge(
        left=base[['Label', col, 'Passengers']], right=legs,
        left_on=col, right_on='Leg',
    )
    merged = merged[merged['LegCapacity'].notna()]

    for i, row in merged.iterrows():
        prob.addConstraint(
            name=f'leg_{row["Label"]}_{row[col].replace("-", "")}',
            constraint=row['Passengers'] <= row['LegCapacity'],
        )

print(prob)
prob.solve()
base[['Passengers', 'Revenue']] = base[['Passengers', 'Revenue']].map(pulp.value)
print(base)

bus_trips:
MAXIMIZE
50*Passengers_ABC_Bus1 + 100*Passengers_ABC_Bus2 + 50*Passengers_ABD_Bus1 + 40*Passengers_ABD_Bus2 + 20*Passengers_AB_Bus1 + 30*Passengers_AB_Bus2 + 0
SUBJECT TO
leg_AB_Bus1_AB: Passengers_AB_Bus1 <= 40

leg_AB_Bus2_AB: Passengers_AB_Bus2 <= 40

leg_ABC_Bus1_AB: Passengers_ABC_Bus1 <= 40

leg_ABC_Bus2_AB: Passengers_ABC_Bus2 <= 40

leg_ABD_Bus1_AB: Passengers_ABD_Bus1 <= 40

leg_ABD_Bus2_AB: Passengers_ABD_Bus2 <= 40

leg_ABC_Bus1_BC: Passengers_ABC_Bus1 <= 50

leg_ABC_Bus2_BC: Passengers_ABC_Bus2 <= 50

leg_ABD_Bus1_BD: Passengers_ABD_Bus1 <= 60

leg_ABD_Bus2_BD: Passengers_ABD_Bus2 <= 60

VARIABLES
0 <= Passengers_ABC_Bus1 <= 20 Integer
0 <= Passengers_ABC_Bus2 <= 30 Integer
0 <= Passengers_ABD_Bus1 <= 20 Integer
0 <= Passengers_ABD_Bus2 <= 30 Integer
0 <= Passengers_AB_Bus1 <= 10 Integer
0 <= Passengers_AB_Bus2 <= 10 Integer
...

Result - Optimal solution found

Objective value:                6700.00000000
Enumerated nodes:               0
Total iterations:               0
Time (CPU seconds):             0.00
Time (Wallclock seconds):       0.00

Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.00   (Wallclock seconds):       0.00

  Itinerary Leg1 Leg2   Bus  Capacity  Price     Label  Passengers  Revenue
0       A-B  A-B  NaN  Bus1        10     20   AB_Bus1        10.0    200.0
1       A-B  A-B  NaN  Bus2        10     30   AB_Bus2        10.0    300.0
2     A-B-C  A-B  B-C  Bus1        20     50  ABC_Bus1        20.0   1000.0
3     A-B-C  A-B  B-C  Bus2        30    100  ABC_Bus2        30.0   3000.0
4     A-B-D  A-B  B-D  Bus1        20     50  ABD_Bus1        20.0   1000.0
5     A-B-D  A-B  B-D  Bus2        30     40  ABD_Bus2        30.0   1200.0


Thanks for the explanation but that is not quite what I'm looking for. I have edited my original post to make it clearer (also changed column name Capacity to Demand so it is more understandable).
